# How to serialize std::chrono::duration with Boost?

Tags: serialization, boost, duration, boost-serialization, c++-chrono

Is it possible to serialize `std::chrono::duration` or especially `std::chrono::milliseconds` with `boost::serialization`?

The following error occurred:

> "struct std::chrono::duration >’ has no member named ‘serialize"

I need this for my template-class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

template<typename T>
class Field {
public:

// Default Constructor
Field() {}

Field(std::string name, T value) :
        mName(name), mValue(value) {}

~Field() {}

const std::string& getName() const {
    return mName;
}

T getValue() const {
    return mValue;
}

private:

friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int) {
    archive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Name", mName);
    archive & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Value", mValue);
}

std::string mName;
T mValue;
};

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION( Field<int>, boost::serialization::object_serializable )
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION( Field<std::chrono::milliseconds>, boost::serialization::object_serializable )
```

I'm creating the following object:

```
Field<std::chrono::milliseconds> mSimTime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
auto earlier = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto aLotOfMilliseconds= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        now - earlier);
```

// Serialize here int64_t.

then after deserialization, you have:

```
std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli> duration(aLotOfMilliseconds);
```